# How to download List from SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, office-365

[image]

Hello, is it possible to download SharePoint list ? As you can see on attached image, I have two types of Documents - Document Library and Lists.

I **have** Download option in the **Document Library** Type as you can see on the image below,

[image]

but I **don't have** that option for **List** Type... My question is, is it possible to download and how ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export lists to Excel or open them in MS Access. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/export-to-excel-from-sharepoint-bfb2ea48-6118-4fa9-abb6-cced9424e5d9

Comment: Thank you , I export list to Excel and I get query.iqy file, and now how to import that file again ?